# How to remove class if the content of an element is equal to another Jquery

Tags: jquery, element, equals, removeclass

I have a problem on my script, i would like to know :

How to remove a class if the content of an element (such as div, img, etc) is equal to another content of another element (such as div, img, etc) ?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: show where in the code is the problem?

Comment: post ur code so we can help youmore

Comment: I would like to show one div particular in removing a class (that display:none). This is complicated to explain, but in order to do it, i would like to know how we can select the content of an element that will be equal to another element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
  if ($("#div1").html() == $("#div2").html()){
   $("#div1").removeClass("clasname");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use id's to manipulate specific elements.

your jquery

```
jQuery('#my_element_that_needs_to_show').removeClass("class_that_has_display_none");
```

your html

```
<div id="my_element_that_needs_to_show" class="class_that_has_display_none">Content bla bla bla </div>
```

your css

```
.class_that_has_display_none {display:none;}
```